# How to get text from an element , when getText fails

Tags: protractor

I have the following element

```js
element(by.css("span[aria-label='Picker ID, TESTUSER']")
```

I want to assure the text on this filed is TESTUSER, so I tried:

```js
 expect(element(by.css("span[aria-label='Picker ID, TESTUSER']")).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('TESTUSER');
```

then I got the error:
`Expected null to equal 'TESTUSER'`

So I tried:

```js
element(by.css("span[aria-label='Picker ID, TESTUSER']")).getText().then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
      })
```

And I got this error:

```js
Expected '' to be 'TESTUSER'.
```

How to get the value of this field and expect it is TESTUSER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in most cases try in the following order:

**getText()** if it doesn't work use **getAttribute('textContent')** if that too doesn't work use **getAttribute('value')**

getAttribute('value') works only if there is an attribute called value in your element (like id, name etc)

So in most cases, if getText doesn't work use **.getAttribute('textContent')**
Use:

```
element(by.css("span[aria-label='Picker ID, TESTUSER']")).getAttribute('textContent')
```

Because getText or text() actually uses innerText ,and will not detect text from hidden elements .

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
>   HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
>   important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and 
>   elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText
>   is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
>   value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
>   styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be
>   avoided when possible.)
>
> Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version
>   11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently
>   destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the
>   nodes again into any other element or the same element after
>   doing so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: tks @PDHide, your suggestion, totally works. I did an updated to print what I wanted:  ```element(by.css("span[aria-label='Picker ID, TESTUSER']")).getAttribute('textContent').then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
        })
```

Comment: @IngriddBrito please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign